# Consuming a Webservice : C# to php

Tags: c#, php, web-services

So i've been running some tests on a webservice and it's runing just fine with my code in C# :

```
    // The objet to do the request
            server.CustomerWS Auth = new server.CustomerWS();

    // The object we will use to store the request
            server.customerXML Cust = new server.customerXML();

            // Request
            Cust = Auth.authenticate(login, password);


            if (cust.retour == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("KO");
            }
```

I need to convert this code to PHP, being a complete noob at this language I would apreciate any help I can get to get me started, the main problem being that I don't know how to handle objects coming from a webservice in PHP.

I'm not using php5 on my server so I can't use the soap php functions.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
// -- specify your Web Service URL and also the login and password (should be really protected : use HTTPS and send these parameters in POST)    
$url = 'http://....';
// The objet to do the request
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

// The object we will use to store the request
$result = NULL;

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement(curl_exec($curl)); 
if ($xml->retour[0] == true){ 
    print ("OK");
}else{
    print("KO");
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, it helps a lot but the web service answers using SOAP (so basically XML) and not json, is there a simple way to translate the response ?

Comment: @Voltneu : i edited my response. a trick : try by var_dump(curl_exec($curl)) before using SimpleXmlElement(). Also in php.ini you must uncomment ;extension=php_curl.dll and restart your Apache